# Bucket is not show on Google Storage list and access is denied for every command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have tried creating a bucket only to receive

> ServiceException: 409 Bucket *BUCKET_NAME* already exists.

Now I don't know where this bucket is, I checked every project, and I do not have permission to do anything.

Anyone had this problem?

Comment: Bucket names are global. Yes we see this problem where someone else has already created a bucket with a name we want. Choose a different name.

Comment: use project_id as prefix to bucket.coz project_id is globally unique

Comment: You can use gcloud command 'gsutil ls -L -b gs://BUCKET_NAME' to get bucket information. It will show you the location of the bucket including project number. For more information please follow the [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-bucket-information#gsutil)

Comment: Would you please use this below mentioned gcloud command to create the bucket. We have naming best practices documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#naming)

>> gsutil -D mb -c DRA -l US-CENTRAL1 gs://your-bucketName-us-central1/

Comment: Just to clarify. Any commands I try to run returns 403 (access denied).
I thought it was global but restricted to my projects, it seens to be global on any project from anyone. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already mentioned in comments, the GCS bucket names are global and, therefore, when creating a bucket you need to make sure its name is unique.

See the [Bucket naming guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets) article from the official GCP documentation for the reference.